# PySpark: get total row count of different combinations over a window partition

Tags: pyspark, partition-by

In PySpark, would it be possible to obtain the total number of rows of different combinations in a particular window?

Example:

```
Original dataset

#+---+---+---+
#|  x|  y|  z|
#+---+---+---+
#|  1|  a|  a|  
#|  1|  a|  a|
#|  1|  a|  b|
#|  2|  c|  a|
#+---+---+---+

Expected result

#+---+---+---+------+
#|  x|  y|  z| count|
#+---+---+---+------+
#|  1|  a|  a|     2|
#|  1|  a|  a|     2|
#|  1|  a|  b|     2|
#|  2|  c|  a|     1|
#+---+---+---+------+
```

In the first three rows I'm expecting count = 2 (not 3) because there are only two combinations (1aa and 1ab)

Thank you

Comment: why `1 a b` count is 2?

Comment: You can also immagine that there are only 2 columns (x & y) with 2 times 1 a and one time 1 b, the count should be 2 for each row